# How do you access structs inside enums?

Tags: struct, enums, rust

The Rust book has [examples of assigning them but not a single one showing how to access them](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch06-01-defining-an-enum.html)

```
pub enum Animal {
    Ant(Ant),
    Bear,
}

pub struct Ant {
    pub species: usize,
}

fn test(a: Ant) {
    println!("{:?}", a.species);
}

fn main() {
    let a: Animal = Animal::Ant(Ant { species: 1 });
    let b: Animal = Animal::Bear;

    test(a);
}
```

How do I get the `Ant` struct in `a` to the `test` function?

Comment: There's nothing special about *structs* vs any other values.

Comment: To be fair the other answer wasn't really satisfying until you updated it to the current Rust-syntax 

Comment: @K.Biermann the most upvoted answer was already using Rust 1.0 syntax (and had been since 2015). Remember that questions can have multiple answers and neither the accepted answer nor the most upvoted answer are necessarily the best answer. It *always* pays to read all the answers.

Comment: From the thread with the answer, is the solution to do this?
`if let Animal::Ant(s) = a {test (Ant{species:s.species});}`
Seems strange.

Comment: Close: `if let Animal::Ant(ant_struct) = animal_enum { test(ant_struct); }` would be the appropriate syntax.

Comment: [`if let Animal::Ant(ant) = a { test(ant); }`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=0b4994d105eac9c349c480231c3f3b8a&version=stable)

Comment: Great. Thank you.

Comment: @Shepmaster Of course you're right; reading all the answers is usually a good idea. I didn't want to be nitpicking.